# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found

Tags: java, spring-boot, controller, jackson

Getting error,

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class com.app.server.data.MyUser and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1191) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:404) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:71) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:33) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:145) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:107) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:400) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1429) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:921) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
```

When call below function from a Spring boot controller,

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class JdbcUserRepository implements UserRepository {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Override
    public List<MyUser> findAll() {

        return jdbcTemplate.query( "select * from users", (rs, rowNum) ->
            new MyUser(
                    rs.getLong("user_id"),
                    rs.getString("user_nid"),
                    rs.getString("user_name"),
                    rs.getString("user_duid")
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class MyUser {

    Long userId;
    String userNid;
    String userName;
    String userDuid;

    public MyUser(Long userId, String userNid, String userName, String userDuid) {
        super();
        this.userId = userId;
        this.userNid = userNid;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.userDuid = userDuid;
    }
}
```

browsers giving error,

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Type definition error: [simple type, class com.app.server.data.MyUser]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class com.app.server.data.MyUser and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0])
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Does MyUser have getters and setters?

Comment: No, I updated the post with MyUser class

Comment: So and getters that the serialize can access the data

Comment: Add both getters and setters if you also want to have objects from JSON

Comment: Thanks Simon, it resolved the issue. You can put it as answer for further reference.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add getter and setters that Jackson can access the object state.

```
public class MyUser {

    Long userId;
    String userNid;
    String userName;
    String userDuid;

    public MyUser(Long userId, String userNid, String userName, String userDuid) {
        super();
        this.userId = userId;
        this.userNid = userNid;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.userDuid = userDuid;
    }

    // public getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Getters only would be enough, even if fields aren't final

Comment: @Václav for serializing yes, but you need them for deserializing

Answer (score 4):

Use (install) lombok to create getters and setters for you. Put @Data annotation above your class.
`@Data class MyUser { int id; }`